# problema para atualizar informações de um site "QueryException"

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, query

Bom dia estou tentando realizar a atualização em um site onde uso o framework laravel, para realizar a atualização realizo o acesso como admin e atribuo as novas informações, contudo sempre quando tento salvar as informações aparece o seguinte erro: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'comission' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `teams` (`name`, `title`, `department`, `comission`, `since`, `lattes`, `photo`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Ellen de Cássia Sousa Parrela, 4, 11, , 2023, [https://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.doperfil/ellen-de-cássia-sousa-parrela1024362023021063e645949fde1.pngid=K4265728E6&tokenCaptchar=03AFY_a8Urb1ZRh2A1wW8Nv1byXD0OYaanLxe0cOYFOlPxLJwvKfbnzNbBJV61PLmkpYjBkcKNve7X9R7qCRQNnouN8NFI8MeBJMZCKWVBmCy_ETP95X5Wj4O-oUtxsY8TLzTguiPNqjcWqsBB1pLV-ap52HyMmPTE5QwCwDqUXUxtKa7SAKXG1_Wuub1moFD1oyRUeDEXX2iZjzyyMGuhQkFtzgE-L5of6AODhR5oseX0xVBzJb6OHK-j2XFT8mKBcJAhPdhfL0XGl56cS2oOwkDtCCCNZt8sdNZxcaRwHwcJI3fXHxBC0Z66p7epknnQrtZfCJkHco603WIS2ZBDPkSVk2wu2IiICaC9hdwnD8vkPl1uVZqIzWIBgJUPbl1l0VA2-VPpQnPDMSj-_JHOAHnQQTy85ux06kaYbT4kcIWbfPF8Lz56b-QmXedIYjlMoEw38TGj1vYgdoVeRMkSnUW2Hoiy1s_T2-i82rNUtVKDsXiym7uD_BaQaZbrHNTuQbZ_ocYbjVg9eemPjaIjy8WVRT4rTum1Gg](https://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/visualizacv.doperfil/ellen-de-c%C3%A1ssia-sousa-parrela1024362023021063e645949fde1.pngid=K4265728E6&tokenCaptchar=03AFY_a8Urb1ZRh2A1wW8Nv1byXD0OYaanLxe0cOYFOlPxLJwvKfbnzNbBJV61PLmkpYjBkcKNve7X9R7qCRQNnouN8NFI8MeBJMZCKWVBmCy_ETP95X5Wj4O-oUtxsY8TLzTguiPNqjcWqsBB1pLV-ap52HyMmPTE5QwCwDqUXUxtKa7SAKXG1_Wuub1moFD1oyRUeDEXX2iZjzyyMGuhQkFtzgE-L5of6AODhR5oseX0xVBzJb6OHK-j2XFT8mKBcJAhPdhfL0XGl56cS2oOwkDtCCCNZt8sdNZxcaRwHwcJI3fXHxBC0Z66p7epknnQrtZfCJkHco603WIS2ZBDPkSVk2wu2IiICaC9hdwnD8vkPl1uVZqIzWIBgJUPbl1l0VA2-VPpQnPDMSj-_JHOAHnQQTy85ux06kaYbT4kcIWbfPF8Lz56b-QmXedIYjlMoEw38TGj1vYgdoVeRMkSnUW2Hoiy1s_T2-i82rNUtVKDsXiym7uD_BaQaZbrHNTuQbZ_ocYbjVg9eemPjaIjy8WVRT4rTum1Gg), 2023-02-10 10:24:36, 2023-02-10 10:24:36, ?))

ja tentei corrigir esse erro acessando o php.ini nas extensões não funcionou. Outro poblema é que nao tenho acesso ao banco de dados do site nem acesso ao servidor do mesmo. Estou a mais de uma dia tentando corrigir se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: comission é a 4@ coluna do insert , não recebe valor ...4, 11, , 2023,.. mas no banco tem uma constraint de not null. Ou se passa um valor ou se elimina a constraint ... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_constraint ...

Comment: Nota , não publique dados pessoais ou reais ainda que públicos.

Answer (score -1):

Como já comentado antes, para corrigir você precisa preencher o campo "comission" pois ele é obrigatório, não pode ser nulo.

Se não tiver como preencher, só modificando a constrain no banco de dados.

Não existe outra forma de correção além das citadas acima, pois é uma regra que está no banco de dados.